# Required item type of the context item for the parent axis is node(); supplied value has item type xs:untypedAtomic

Tags: xslt

I am getting this error in my XSLT and I do not know why:

```
Required item type of the context item for the parent axis is node(); supplied value has item type xs:untypedAtomic
```

I am getting it at this line:

```
<xsl:when test="../../Ratios/Ratio[@id=$Ratio]/RatioElementValue[@year=$YEAR][@displayValue != '' and contains(@displayValue, '(') and contains(@displayValue, ')')]">
```

It is inside a choose statement

```
<xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="../../Ratios/Ratio[@id=$Ratio]/RatioElementValue[@year=$YEAR][@displayValue != '' and contains(@displayValue, '(') and contains(@displayValue, ')')]">
             NA
         </xsl:when>
         <xsl:otherwise>
             <xsl:value-of select="../../Ratios/Ratio[@id=$Ratio]/RatioElementValue[@year=$YEAR]/@displayValue"/>
         </xsl:otherwise>
     </xsl:choose>
```

Comment: Well, show us the context, i.e. the ancestor elements of the `xsl:choose/xsl:when`. I suppose you have some `for-each` or other instruction changing the context item to something that is not a node.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I solved it thanks to your input! I had a distinct-values in a for each statement.